# How to integrate Webssh with Django?

Tags: django, nginx, ssh

I am running a Django Nginx Gunicorn server and also running a web SSH service with a systemd process. Basically, Nginx runs the main domain example.com and then a systemd process listens on port 4433 at example.com:4433. The reason for this is so users can remote login in to different computers using the website instead of having to use a local shell.

The rest of the website is behind a login because Django controls the views. However, the part of the website behind the port is being served by systemd and webssh. Is there a way I can integrate Django with Webssh in order to lock the domain example.com:4433 behind a login?